# Laravel Sanctum returns 404 instead of 401 unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

I am using laravel/sanctum package for authenticating my api. I have followed all the steps from the documentation but I get 404 not found when using an invalid token for hitting a guarded route instead of 401.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::post("/upload", [AuthController::class, "uploadFile"]);
    Route::post('/me', [AuthController::class, 'me']);
});
```

Comment: How are you calling the route?

Answer (score 0):

few steps to follow

1. clear cache
2. test.ca/api/upload - make sure you have 'api' in url (from where you are calling)
3. add 'Accept application/json' in your request header.